# Trigger Worksheet_change event when ActiveX combobox value change

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I have many ActiveX Combo box related to the cells of a column. I create them when you click on a cell (within Worksheet_SelectionChange). The cell below (hidden by) the combobox is the related linkedCell of the combobox.

I would like to trigger a Worksheet_change event when the value of the covered cell changes (so when I change the value on the combobox).

I discovered that only manual changes trigger the Worksheet_change event. How can I enable it also for changes performed by the combobox?

Comment: Don't use the Linkedcell but refer to a Cell in the Change-event of the combobox

Comment: what if I have multiplce combobox? I mean a non predefined number of those

Comment: Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Range(ComboBox1.TopLeftCell.Address).Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Comment: It doens't trigger the worksheet_change event

Comment: Try again, it certainly does

Comment: I've also added a msgbox on top of worksheet_change, and it's not called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196695/discussion-between-evr-and-andrea-giordano).